# How to properly design a method to populate an array

Tags: java, arrays

I the beginning of my game I am creating a background that consists of star objects

```
bg = new Background();
```

My background class looks like this:

```
public class Background {

    public ArrayList<Star> starList;
    private Star star;

    public Background(int level) {
        star = new Star();
        star.populateStarList(level);
    }

    public class Star{

        private boolean stillSearching = true;
        boolean clash = false;
        public Vector2 starPositionVector;

        public Star() {
            //loop through the starList to find valid x,y coordinates
            while (stillSearching){
                float x = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((GamePanel.WIDTH - 0) + 1));
                float y = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((GamePanel.HEIGHT - 0) + 1));
                starPositionVector = new Vector2(x,y);

                for (int u = 0; u < starList.size(); u++){
                    Star starCollision = starList.get(u);

                    //check distance
                    if (starPositionVector.dstSqr(starCollision.starPositionVector) < 5){
                        clash = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (clash == false){
                    stillSearching = false;
                }
            }
        }


        public void populateStarList(int level){

            if(starList==null) {
                starList = new ArrayList<Star>();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                Star star = new Star();
                starList.add(star);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that populateStarList will fill an array with star objects. However, I cannot call populateStarlist without instantiating the star class. This is a problem as the starList array is used in the

```
public class Star
```

and is zero before the populateStarlist is called.

I am not sure whether this is me not understanding how to use static methods or if I've made some poor design choices.

ps: if there is a more effecient way to test for a valid x,y coordinate than my while/for loop I would be happy to know.

Comment: why isn't populateStarlist called by the constructor?

Comment: Yes, you have a bad design. Also, your while/for loop is odd, why are you using random numbers to find collisions? I would use a heirarchy, where there are stars and the "starscape" creates the stars. Then the star should provide a circle (center and radius) where the collisions will happen. The star should not know about the starscape.

Comment: Hmm, I guess the populateStarList can be in the background class and called from its constructor rather than belonging to the star class. In regards to the while/for loop. Right now I create a new star object and give it a random x,y coordinate. I then check to see if this coordinate clashes.. if it does (clash = true) I break out and assign a new x,y coordinate. If I reach the end of the starList and no clashes has been found I set stillSearching to false to break out of the while loop.

Comment: I think that would be a good start to improving your design. If you explain better the purpose of starPositionVector I wouldn't mind giving you advice on you loop, but to be honest it looks like you are getting a bit ahead of yourself in trying to accomplish more advanced tasks than you are ready for. Are you trying to create stars that do not lie within a squared distance of 5 from each other?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, basically I am just making a background with filled circles (stars) that should not overlap. Hence I set their distance to be minimum 5 (squared distance for optimized performance). The while/for loop works nicely - but I am sure it can be made more elegant.

Comment: I think what you have for the loop is just fine, I misinterpreted it's purpose earlier. It's only done once I assume and you don't have so many stars that it's going to be very slow. It is an O(n^2) algorithm, and there is an O(n) algorithm I can think of, but that only begins to matter if you have so many stars that the algorithm you're using becomes too slow to be usable.